# EF 6 Ghost/Random records added when saving

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, duplicates, ghost

I am having a problem that is extremely strange to me. I am working with EF6 and am modifying records in the database and then saving them. HOWEVER, on variable objects that have a foreign key, even though it exists in the db, it is randomly adding a new record to the table.

**Example:**
So if I have a CRec table that has a foriegn key to the Rect table, when I modify the CRec variable and save it, it is adding another entry to the Rect table.

I would add code but all I am doing is

```
ctxAcct.Entry(crec).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Any ideas would be appreicated!

**Edit**
Workflow: User logins --> Opens their CRec --> edits --> clicks save.

With this being EF codefirst MVC, the below method is called from the view. oCRec is filled with foreign key values. So I will have a VendorID and a VendorID_ID.  VendorID_ID is essentially a foreignkey field to the Vendor table.

When I hit save changes it is randomly adding a duplicate VendorID_ID when I haven't even touched that field.

```
Public void UpdateCRec(CRec oCRec)
{
    ctxAcct.Entry(oCRec).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    ctxAcct.SaveChanges();
    //here I am making some changes and doing some calculations with other fields in the database.
    //Now, after changing field values in CRec I move to the save changes method.
    ctxAcct.Entry(oCRec).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ctxAcct.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: We need more code. Fore example, method that edits crec

Comment: Give us more code plz.